# Problem running react in apache localhost server

Tags: reactjs, apache, react-router

I have designed a website in react and build it successfully. I uploaded all the files inside the build directory to my localhost running apache server.

When I start my apache server my react app runs well and React routers are also running well that is I can navigate between different states.

For example say, `http:localhost` runs well and when I navigate to say `http:localhost\test` using a link in the app it also works but I don't find any page source for this new page `http:localhost\test`. If I go to url section of `http:localhost\test` and hit enter it also says page not found.

So, the problem is although I can navigate to `http:localhost\test` from `http:localhost` but if I refresh the `test` page all vanishes. As I can I can understand there is no resource on that url but why it works first time only and not second time if I refresh the page as I mentioned.

Any explanation will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: See if anything from the [create-react-app deployment/server docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing) helps. The gist is that the server needs to redirect page requests to the root index.html file so the app loads and can handle routing internally.

Comment: @DrewReese the app loads but when I refresh it vanishes.

Comment: Right, because the server ***isn't*** handling the nested page request properly. It loads on `"/"` just fine because that's where the app is hosted/served from. It needs to handle page quests for nested directories that *don't exist*.